# Back calculating the input from output signal chain with an isolated amplifier and opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, analog, isolation

We are measuring the voltage of a charger using the below circuit with the help of an ADC present in a microcontroller.

The value of charger voltage is required for some other applications. The value of charger voltage is used to calculate isolation resistance.

I tried to calculate the input from the output. I am getting an error of almost 2 V in my calculations.

We are using an [AMC1350](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/amc1350-q1.pdf?ts=1684997960639&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) and a [TLV6001](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv6001.pdf?ts=1684982300503&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTLV6001) in the signal chain.

Please see my circuit diagram and calculations below.

[image]

[image]

From the circuit diagram you can see that the input V2 is 58 V. I used the equation shown in the second image to calculate V2 from Vout.

I am getting a value of 56 V instead of 58 V. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Note that "impedance" (R3//R6 + R8) (for Vref) is not the same that R5.

Comment: @Antonio51,will correct it.For analysis I took Vref directly

Comment: What is the worst-case stackup of resistor tolerances? And what is the resolution (referred to the output) of your ADC?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast,0.1% tolerance resistors.ADC resolution is 12bits,Vref is 5V

Answer (score 2):

Given this differential stage:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEthnf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The relationship is:

$$ V_{OUT} = V_{REF}\frac{R_3}{R_3+R_4}\left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\right) + V_A\frac{R_4}{R_3+R_4}\left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\right) - V_B\frac{R_2}{R_1} $$

That's horrendous. It can be simplified by setting \$R_1 = R_3\$ and \$R_2 = R_4\$. Then it becomes:

$$ V_{OUT} = V_{REF} + \frac{R_2}{R_1}(V_A - V_B) $$

While that's much simpler, it isn't what you've built. I believe you have failed to account for the impedance of the source of \$V_{REF}=+2.5V\$, using R3 and R6 in your original circuit. If I convert the system composed of the 5V source, and R3 and R6, into their Thevenin equivalent, you'll see what I mean:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft4ndt.png)</sup>

You haven't accounted for this extra impedance of 500Ω in your own circuit. It appears in series with your R8, so your differential amplifier is equivalent to this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9DUjd.png)</sup>

Plugging in all these values into the terrifying equation above, I get this relationship:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT} &= 2.5\frac{10k}{10k+8.75k}\left(1+\frac{8.25k}{10k}\right) + V_A\frac{8.75k}{10k+8.75k}\left(1+\frac{8.25k}{10k}\right) - V_B\frac{8.25k}{10k} \\ \\
&= 0.973V_{REF} + 0.852V_A - 0.825V_B
\end{aligned}
$$

I can't know if that's the relationship you measured yourself. I can say, though, that if you want the simple relationship \$V_{OUT} = V_{REF} + \frac{R_2}{R_1}(V_A - V_B)\$, then you must adjust for the extra impedance of the 2.5V source. It's easy enough to do, just subtract the 500Ω Thevenin resistance from R8, to get this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqnA4a.png)</sup>

Here I've set \$R_4 = 8.25k\Omega - 500\Omega = 7.75k\Omega \$, which will yield the following input-output relationship:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT} &= V_{REF} + \frac{R_2}{R_1}(V_A - V_B)  \\ \\
&= V_{REF} + 0.825(V_A - V_B)
\end{aligned}
$$

That's probably more like what you intended.

Comment: In this calculation I took Vref value that I obtained in the simulation 2.48V(1st image) and subistitued in equation of V2(2nd image last)

Answer (score 0):

The culprit here was the input impedance of AMC1350.It's value is 1.25 MΩ (typ).

To solve this I reduced the value of resistors present in the voltage divider network.

Please see the circuit below.

[image]

Now when I am back calculating,I am getting the value of Vin as expected(58V)

More Details

**Voltage at the input of AMC1350 before changing the value of resistor present in the voltage divider.**

[image]

**The expected voltage at the input of AMC1350 is 2.3766V**

[image]

The loss of voltage at the input of AMC1350 is due to it's input impedance of 1.25Mega ohm.

For verifying this I put a resistor of value 1.25Mega ohm in parallel with R2 and obtained a value of 2.294V.

[image]